# How to return the real/imaginary part of a symbolic polynomial in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, symbols, polynomial-math, complex-numbers, symbolic-math

Given a polynomial such as `(a+b*i)*c+i`, where `a`, `b`, `c` are defined as symbolic elements to represent three real values and `i` is the imaginary unit, how to return the real part and imaginary part of this polynomial?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = sym('a','real');
b = sym('b','real');
c = sym('c','real');
expand(real((a+b*1i)*c+1i))
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapidly reply. It works for the polynomial of (a+b*1i)*c+1i. But when I tried to use it on a more sophisticated polynomial, the return value still contains the imaginary unit i.

Comment: may be res = simplify(real((a+b*1i)*c+1i)); or res = simple(real((a+b*1i)*c+1i)); will help

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. It also works well for the sophisticated polynomial after a more clear clarification of each polynomial.